# Get UserData - JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, user-profile, user

As seen in the following picture, when I add a User-Filter to a page it allows me to choose the parameter to pass. In my case I used the `Büro`.

[image]

How can I retrive this data from client using JavaScript? I already tried with the following code, but the fields I need are not in this object.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var web = context.get_web();
var user = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting only the current user won't be enough to get user profile properties. You need to use the PeopleManager as well. Your code should look something like this:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var web = context.get_web();
var user = web.get_currentUser();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
var personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(user.get_loginName());
context.load(personProperties);
context.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);

function onRequestSuccess() {
    // Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
    var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_displayName();

    // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
    messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
        + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
    $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

Since I don't have access to DEV environment now, I can't tell you for sure, but you might need to add domain name in front of user.get_loginName() on the following line of code. As far as I remember it should be DOMAIN\USERNAME:

```
var personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(user.get_loginName());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you found it helpful, mark it as an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Of course...the system says i have to wait 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 3):

Since I have to load the userprofile script, I had to use:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var personProperties = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext).getMyProperties();
    clientContext.load(personProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Office'];
        })
    });
```